# Get Milliseconds from Ticks in DateTime c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a simple DateTime object, equal to the date: `11/1/2020 8:11:14 AM`.

I want to convert it to milliseconds so I do:
`myTimestamp?.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond`.

I get `63739786274788`, which seems correct from the pure calculation perspective.

However, when I input it into one of the [online converters](https://currentmillis.com/) to validate, I get the date `Wed Nov 01 3989 01:11:14`, which is of course way off.

Questions:

1. What is this number `63739786274788` if not time in ms?
2. How do I get "normal" timestamp in ms?

Comment: There are three starting times 1) 1/1/01 2) 1/1/1900 3) 1/1/1970  Which one do you have?

Comment: You mention `DateTime`, `TimeStamp`, converting to milliseconds but refusing to use `DateTime.TotalMilliseconds` and some random assumptions about the internals of `DateTime`. Can you order your thoughts and just ask what you need to ask?

Comment: @Blindy - `TotalMilliseconds` is not a property of `DateTime`.  You may be thinking of `TimeSpan`, which is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET, `DateTime` ticks are based on an epoch of `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000`.  The `.Kind` property is used to decide whether that is UTC, local time, or "unspecified".

Most online converters, such as the one you linked to, are expecting a [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), where the value is based on an epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.  It is always UTC based.  (The precision varies, both seconds and milliseconds are commonly used.)

If you want to get a milliseconds-based Unix Timestamp From .NET, instead of dividing you should use the built-in functions [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds) and [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds).  (There are also seconds-based versions of these functions.)

Assuming your input values are UTC-based:

```cs
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2020, 11, 1, 8, 11, 14, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt);
long timestamp = dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

// output:  1604218274000
```

`DateTimeKind.Local` will also work with this, assuming your values are indeed based on the computer's local time zone.  `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` is a bit trickier, as you'll need to convert to a `DateTimeOffset` with a specific time zone using `TimeZoneInfo` first.

You could also construct the `DateTimeOffset` value directly, rather than go through `DateTime` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so you start off dividing Ticks by System.TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond (10,000)

As you can see, the number you generated is much larger than the current milliseconds:

63739786274788

1607363529803

The short answer is that Ticks are based off of 12:00:00 midnight January 1, 0001 and a your online calculator is based off of unix time, January 1, 1970.  So that would explain why you're about 2,000 years off.  If you subtracted the Ticks from a new DateTime(1970,1,1), then that would give you about the right number to satisfy the online calculator.

For more info, I would suggest reading through [MS's docs on DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0)